# How to test an initialize method that returns "this" with a only one if condition to set the internal data

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

I try to figure out how to test this kind of method

```
// Let's say models === null when we instantiate
public initialize(mongodb: MongoDb): this {
    if (!this.models) {
      this.models = {
        users: new models.UserModel(mongodb),
      };
    }
    return this;
  }

  public getModels(): Models | null {
    return this.models || null;
  }
```

My coverage is still staying that I didn't test the if part... This is not really true because when I ask for the `getModels` I can test its value (so implicitly the if.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you share your test code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import * as models from './models';
import { MongoDb, Models } from './interfaces';

export class UserDataSource {
  private models: Models | null = null;
  public initialize(mongodb: MongoDb): this {
    if (!this.models) {
      this.models = {
        users: new models.UserModel(mongodb)
      };
    }
    return this;
  }

  public getModels(): Models | null {
    return this.models || null;
  }
}
```

Unit test, `index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { UserDataSource } from './';
import { MongoDb } from './interfaces';
import * as models from './models';

describe('UserDataSource', () => {
  const mockedMongodb: MongoDb = {};
  describe('#initialize', () => {
    it('should initlialize models correctly', () => {
      const userDataSource = new UserDataSource();
      const actualValue = userDataSource.initialize(mockedMongodb);
      expect(userDataSource.getModels()).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ users: expect.any(models.UserModel) }));
      expect(actualValue).toBe(userDataSource);
    });
    it('should not initialize models', () => {
      const userDataSource = new UserDataSource();
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      userDataSource['models'] = [];
      const actualValue = userDataSource.initialize(mockedMongodb);
      expect(actualValue).toBe(userDataSource);
    });
  });

  describe('#getModels', () => {
    it('should get models correctly', () => {
      const userDataSource = new UserDataSource();
      const actualValue = userDataSource.getModels();
      expect(actualValue).toEqual(null);
    });

    it('should get models correctly and not null', () => {
      const userDataSource = new UserDataSource();
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      userDataSource['models'] = [];
      const actualValue = userDataSource.getModels();
      expect(actualValue).toEqual([]);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/52729002/index.spec.ts
  UserDataSource
    #initialize
      ✓ should initlialize models correctly (5ms)
      ✓ should not initialize models (7ms)
    #getModels
      ✓ should get models correctly (1ms)
      ✓ should get models correctly and not null (1ms)

-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File             |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 52729002        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  index.ts       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 52729002/models |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  UserModel.ts   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  index.ts       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.157s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/52729002